# How can I execute recipe iff a file exists?

Tags: shell, gnu-make

I'm writing a Makefile recipe that needs to execute IF AND ONLY IF a certain file exists...

Here's what I have:

```
clean:
    $(if $(shell test -s ${MFN_LSTF}), \
        $(foreach mfn, $(shell cat ${MFN_LSTF}), \
            $(MAKE) -f mfd/${mfn} clean;), )
.PHONY: clean
```

${MFN_LSTF} holds a filename that contains a one column list of makefile names that are assumed to be at the same local directory as this makefile recipe.

The problem that I've encountered with is that, the `foreach` statement executes always.  I want it to execute ONLY IF the filename `${MFN_LSTF}` exists.

I've tried this also:

```
clean:
    [ test -s ${MFN_LSTF} ] &&
        for mfn in $(shell cat ${MFN_LSTF}); do
            $(MAKE) -f mfd/${mfn} clean
        done
.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: `$(shell test -s unquoted list)` is going to produce an error message if there is more than one thing in the list. Is there a reason not to just use the shell to do the whole thing rather than getting make to emulate the shell?

Comment: @icarus MF_NAMES_LST is a variable holds a filename.  How can I avoid make to emulate the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a possible and simpler solution, emulating the shell:

```
    $(eval mfn_lstf := $(shell cat ${MFN_LSTF}))
    $(foreach mfn, ${mfn_lstf}, $(MAKE) -f mfd/${mfn} clean;)
```

And, the following works, without emulating the shell:

```
    if [ -s "$${MFN_LSTF}" ]; then \
        while IFS= read -r mfn; do \
            $(MAKE) -f "mfd/$${mfn}" clean; \
        done < "$${MFN_LSTF}"; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the shell part in a recipie.

```
clean:
        F="$MF_NAMES_LIST" ;\
        if [ -e "$$F" ] ; then \
                for mfn in $$(cat "$$F") ; do \
                         $(MAKE) -f mfd/$${mfn} clean;\
                done ; \
        fi
```

Things to note are that if you want the shell to see a dollar you need to double it, and that you want the program to be one logical line so make gives it to a single shell.

GNUmake has an extension to allow you to run an entire recipie in a single shell.

Reading a file with cat into a for loop is not best practice, it goes wrong if there are spaces in the file for example, but I am not fixing that here to keep the code close to the original.

Comment: how should I write it if I were to follow the best practices?

Comment: Use a `while` loop with `read` to process it one line at a time, use `-r` as a flag to read to do a raw read, set `IFS` and use double quotes in the use of the variable to avoid word splitting.

Comment: Thank you very much @icarus.  I updated my possible solution following your recommendations.